# Why does Rust try to borrow *self as mutable again, when it already holds a mutable borrow?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why does the program below produce the following error? Is there anything I can do to fix the error without changing the program flow?

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:10:39
   |
9  |         for bar in &mut self.bars {
   |                    --------------
   |                    |
   |                    first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                    first borrow later used here
10 |             bar.add_foo_value_and_inc(self);
   |                                       ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

The program:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    add_value: u32,
    bars: Vec<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn add_value_to_bars(&mut self) {
        for bar in &mut self.bars {
            bar.add_foo_value_and_inc(self);
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    value: u32,
}

impl Bar {
    fn add_foo_value_and_inc(&mut self, foo: &mut Foo) {
        self.value += foo.add_value;
        foo.add_value += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo{add_value: 1, bars: vec![Bar{value:2}, Bar{value:3}]};
    foo.add_value_to_bars();
}
```

It seems to me that function `add_value_to_bars` already holds a mutable reference to `self` (this is the parameter of the function). So, why does it try to borrow `self` as mutable *again* when it calls `bar.add_foo_value_and_inc`?

Note: this is a minimal program to reproduce the problem, so it isn't intended to be sensible.

Edit: @Herohtar comments that "It is add_foo_value_and_inc that is trying to mutably borrow self
while add_value_to_bars already holds a mutable reference, thus it is being borrowed a second time."

If that is the cause, then why does the following code compile an run without any problems?

Function `add_three` already holds a mutable reference to `x`. Function `add_two` takes a mutable
reference to `x` *again* but in this case it does not cause any problem

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x: u32 = 1234;
    add_three(&mut x);
}

fn add_three(x: &mut u32) {
    add_two(x);
    add_one(x);
}

fn add_two(x: &mut u32) {
    *x += 2;
}

fn add_one(x: &mut u32) {
    *x += 1;
}
```

Comment: It is `add_foo_value_and_inc` that is trying to mutably borrow `self` while `add_value_to_bars` already holds a mutable reference, thus it is being borrowed a second time.

Comment: In `add_three`, the borrow checker understands that you are _handing off_ your mutable reference to a different function. Then, that function ends and you "reborrow" the mutable reference back. This is safe (i.e., does not produce two mutable refs to the same thing) since the called function, having ended, no longer has one. In `add_foo_value_and_inc(self)`, you're saying "do whatever you want to `self`" - but unlike the prior case you cannot reborrow since you still need exclusive access to `self.bars` for iteration. I'm positive there is a duplicate question for this, but I can't find it...

Comment: @GManNickG is correct; in the new example, you are only borrowing one at a time. In the original example, `self` is still borrowed by the `for` loop at the time that you call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Rust doing what Rust is designed to do: prevent you from using memory in an unsafe way.

A mutable reference to `self.bars` was borrowed and given to an implicitly-created `std::slice::IterMut` value (the iterator the loop is using).  Because of this, `self` can't be mutably borrowed within the loop -- it contains `self.bars`, which is already borrowed.

If Rust allowed this to happen, there would be two concurrently-existing mutable references through which `self.bars` could be changed, which is **exactly** what the borrow checker is designed to prevent.

There is a solution, however: you **can** borrow a **different part** of `self` within the loop.  If you change `Bar::add_foo_value_and_inc` to accept `&mut u32` instead of `&mut Foo` then you can borrow `self.add_value`, which is the only field this method modifies anyway.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    add_value: u32,
    bars: Vec<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn add_value_to_bars(&mut self) {
        for bar in &mut self.bars {
            bar.add_foo_value_and_inc(&mut self.add_value);
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    value: u32,
}

impl Bar {
    fn add_foo_value_and_inc(&mut self, foo_value: &mut u32) {
        self.value += *foo_value;
        *foo_value += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo{add_value: 1, bars: vec![Bar{value:2}, Bar{value:3}]};
    foo.add_value_to_bars();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting used to the fact that the borrow-checker is checking for things that would potentially be a problem in multi-threaded code but which are in fact not a problem in single-threaded code (which this is).

Comment: @BrunoRijsman Your original code could be a problem even in single-threaded code. What if `add_foo_value_and_inc` did `foo.bars.clear()`?

Comment: @GManNickG Ah yes, you are right.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman What GMan said. Also, Rust is designed to be conservative and reject possibly-okay programs if it means always rejecting bad programs. However, consider if this example were even slightly more complicated, we might think it's okay when it actually isn't, and Rust would've pointed that out to us. Rust doesn't consider what's happening in `Bar::add_foo_value_and_inc()`, it just sees that you're trying to borrow an already-mutably-borrowed value and stops its analysis there. Functions are opaque boundaries to the borrow checker.